# scipy sparse matrix: remove the rows whose all elements are zero

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I have a sparse matrix which is transformed from sklearn tfidfVectorier. I believe that some rows are all-zero rows. I want to remove them. However, as far as I know, the existing built-in functions, e.g. nonzero() and eliminate_zero(), focus on zero entries, rather than rows.

Is there any easy way to remove all-zero rows from a sparse matrix?

Example:
What I have now (actually in sparse format):

```
[ [0, 0, 0]
  [1, 0, 2]
  [0, 0, 1] ]
```

What I want to get:

```
[ [1, 0, 2]
  [0, 0, 1] ]
```

Answer (score 15):

Slicing + `getnnz()` does the trick:

```
M = M[M.getnnz(1)>0]
```

Works directly on `csr_array`.
You can also remove all 0 columns without changing formats:

```
M = M[:,M.getnnz(0)>0]
```

However if you want to remove both you need

```
M = M[M.getnnz(1)>0][:,M.getnnz(0)>0] #GOOD
```

I am not sure why but

```
M = M[M.getnnz(1)>0, M.getnnz(0)>0] #BAD
```

does not work.

Answer (score 5):

There aren't existing functions for this, but it's not too bad to write your own:

```
def remove_zero_rows(M):
  M = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(M)
```

First, convert the matrix to [CSR (compressed sparse row)](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) format. This is important because CSR matrices store their data as a triple of `(data, indices, indptr)`, where `data` holds the nonzero values, `indices` stores column indices, and `indptr` holds row index information. The docs explain better:

> the column indices for row i are stored in
>   `indices[indptr[i]:indptr[i+1]]` and their corresponding values are
>   stored in `data[indptr[i]:indptr[i+1]]`.

So, to find rows without any nonzero values, we can just look at successive values of `M.indptr`. Continuing our function from above:

```
  num_nonzeros = np.diff(M.indptr)
  return M[num_nonzeros != 0]
```

The second benefit of CSR format here is that it's relatively cheap to slice rows, which simplifies the creation of the resulting matrix.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your reply, @perimosocordiae

I just find another solution by myself. I am posting here in case someone may need it in the future.

```
def remove_zero_rows(X)
    # X is a scipy sparse matrix. We want to remove all zero rows from it
    nonzero_row_indice, _ = X.nonzero()
    unique_nonzero_indice = numpy.unique(nonzero_row_indice)
    return X[unique_nonzero_indice]
```

Comment: X must be a csr, but this works. I could not get the other methods to work for me.