# Sparse matrix: removal of rows if their sum is lower than X (Scipy)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

Let's say, I have the following sparse matrix:

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
m = coo_matrix(([1,1,1,3,2], ([1,2,2,3,4],[1,1,2,3,3])))
print(m.toarray())

>>> array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
>>>       [0, 1, 0, 0],
>>>       [0, 1, 1, 0],
>>>       [0, 0, 0, 3],
>>>       [0, 0, 0, 2]])
```

And I want to keep only those row which sum is bigger than 1. I thought that the following would work.

```
csr = m.tocsr()
csr[(csr.sum(1) > 1)]
```

But it didn't. Instead I had to do a transformation to a numpy array (using `squeeze`):

```
csr = m.tocsr()
csr = csr[np.asarray(csr.sum(1) > 1).squeeze()]
csr.toarray()
```

So, I get what I want:

```
array([[0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 2]], dtype=int64)
```

Is there a more straightforward way of doing this?

I know there is similar answers like 
After checking some other answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31188141/scipy-sparse-matrix-remove-the-rows-whose-all-elements-are-zero), but in their case (with `M.getnnz(1)>0`), the function returns an array directly.

Comment: You could use ravel, but I don't think is more straightfoward.

Comment: @DaniMesejo, wouldn't it be the same? `csr[np.asarray(csr.sum(1) > 1).ravel()]` instead of `csr[np.asarray(csr.sum(1) > 1).squeeze()]`. Or, how do you mean? Is `ravel()` more efficient?

Comment: This should work: `csr[np.ravel(csr.sum(1) > 1), :]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the details:

```
In [803]: m = sparse.csr_matrix(([1,1,1,3,2], ([1,2,2,3,4],[1,1,2,3,3])))                              
In [804]: m                                                                                            
Out[804]: 
<5x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.longlong'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [805]: m.A                                                                                          
Out[805]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 2]], dtype=int64)
In [806]: m.sum(axis=1)                                                                                
Out[806]: 
matrix([[0],
        [1],
        [2],
        [3],
        [2]])
```

`sum` on `ndarray` reduces the dimensions (unless `keepdims` is set).  But `sparse` copies `np.matrix`, and preserves dimensions.  So the result is a (5,1) matrix.

`np.matrix` has a abbreviation for the `array/ravel` step:

```
In [807]: m.sum(axis=1).A1                                                                             
Out[807]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 2])
```

And the indexing:

```
In [811]: m[m.sum(axis=1).A1>1,:]                                                                      
Out[811]: 
<3x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.longlong'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [812]: _.A                                                                                          
Out[812]: 
array([[0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 2]], dtype=int64)
```

I've mentioned elsewhere that `csr` matrix indexing (usually) uses an 'extractor matrix' and matrix multiplication.  This is robust and reasonable give how data is stored, but it isn't nearly as fast or powerful as dense array indexing.

Sometimes we gain speed by acting on the underlying attributes of the matrix, the `data`, `indices` and `indptr`.  But that requires more understanding of that representation, so I won't go into details here.

Comment: looking at the details is how i got to my solution. I didn't know about `.A1` but it is equivalent to `np.asarray(x).ravel()`, as documented [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.A1.html). `squeeze()` is similar to `ravel()` but only works in 1d matrix, so I guess is safer, in the sense of avoiding programming mistakes. I was looking for a more straightforward way of doing it; and `A1` does the trick.

Comment: that `A1` conversion is cheap

Comment: +1, I just noticed that you also created the `csr_matrix` directly. Not part of the question, but I have an the unnecessary conversion on my code as well